# how does sort function in c++ work?

Tags: c++, sorting

In the following code, how does the `sort()` function work?
For example, if we have an array:

```
a [5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

and I sort it in descending order using my `bool cmp()` function,
I want to know: How does it work, which element is `int a` and which is `int b` (the parameters in the `bool cmp()` function), when does it sort, and when does `bool cmp()` return 1 and when does it return 0?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
bool cmp (int a , int b)
{
    return (a > b );
}

int main ()
{
    int a[100];
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i=0 ; i<n ;i++)
        cin >> a[i];

    sort(a,a+n,cmp);
    cout << endl << endl;
    for (int i=0 ; i<n ;i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at a good C++ reference, e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort.

Comment: If you want to know how it is implemented, just look it up in the header file that you included (`algorithm`).

Comment: @us2012 that is horrible advice.  `std::sort` is written to be fast, not readable.

Comment: @Yakk I beg to differ. For a general overview of how it *works*, Oli has posted a link that explains that. As my comment says, if you want to know how it is *implemented*, you have to read the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

How it is implemented is up to the implementation of the standard library. It is guaranteed to have `O(Nlog(N))` complexity. Common implementations use [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) or [introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort).

The comparison function is a binary function that must return `true` if the first argument is *strictly less than* the second. The implementation uses this function to compare two elements of the container to determine which should precede which others - so `a` and `b` may be any two elements in your container. This function must give a strict weak ordering over the elements. That is:

- An element is never less than itself
- If `x < y`, then it is not the case that `y < x`
- If `x < y` and `y < z`, then `x < z`

If you don't supply a comparison function, `operator<` is used. Equivalently, you could pass `std::less` as the comparison function.

Comment: Really, really nit picky: if you don't supply a comparison function, `std::less` is used.  `std::less`, if unspecialized, uses `operator<`, except on pointers, on which it uses an unspecified operation that totally orders pointers (which `<` is not guaranteed to do), which on many modern systems just happens to be `<`.

Comment: @Yakk My copy of the standard says "For all algorithms that take `Compare`, there is a version that uses `operator<` instead." I can't find anything about it using `std::less`.

Comment: Damn -- that would mean that `std::sort` on pointers without using `std::less` is a bad idea.  (Well, not in practice)

Answer (score 0):

Check the reference of sort method here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

The first parameter is the starting pointer.
The second parameter is the ending pointer.
The third parameter is optional. It is the comparison function to define how to sort.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Please try to put the content of the article in your answer! :P